# Best Practice for denying/killing specific URL requests ASP.Net IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis-7.5, requestfiltering

I have an mvc/forms hybrid webapplication hosted on a windows 2008 r2 instance on Azure. The webserver is IIS 7.5 . For the last 4-5 months my server is getting absolutely hammered by vulnerability scanners checking for php related vulnerabilities. example:

```
The controller for path '/wp-login.php' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

from Elmah

So I've gone in and specifically filtered .php and .cgi file extension requests in IIS 7.5 which is working great. However i am still getting hammered for requests like:

```
The controller for path '/admin/Cms_Wysiwyg/directive/' was not found or does not implement IController. 

The controller for path '/phpmyadmin2018/' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

etc. etc. It's more an annoyance as everything is logged, a 404 is returned and it's all a useless resource throwaway.

Through Elmah i've queried a distinct list of URLs related to all these requests. What is the best way to short-circuit these requests? It would be good if i could optionally ban the IP's but right now there are 700 unique IPs making these requests in the last 3 months alone. Main priority is to just short circuit the requests from the dictionary of URLs I know are bogus and avoid the logging and response from my webserver. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

half pseudo code, but I think it will be helpful;

in Global.asax.cs:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        if(checkUrl(url)){
           // your code here
        }

        if (UserIsBanned(GetUserIp()))
        {
            Response.Write("ban");
            Response.End();
        }
    }

    private string GetUserIp()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    }
```

Comment: Yes this is useful. Thanks. If i have a dictionary/array/collection of say of ~400 "bad" url's how resource intensive would this be in terms of response time for regular "good" requests?

Comment: probably ok, you can always measure it, you can also ask a separate question for the performance of looking up in the dictionary and how much will this slow down the request